# How to prevent the overlay of a div during responsive design?

Tags: html, css

When I resize the screen the background color of the div is changed to black (background of div in the next line) instead of maroon.
Please refer this jsfiddle link:

[ https://jsfiddle.net/0j2n1s3d/3/ ]

```
<!Doctype Html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\style3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="head">
        <div class="head-common">
    <div class="head-outer-div">
        <div class="head-inner-div">
            <p class="head-inner-parag">But who has any right to find fault with a man.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="head-inner-div1">
            <div class="search-div">
            <input type="text" value="&emsp;Search Here..." class="head-input">
<button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div></div>
        </div></div>
</header>
<section class="attention">
    <div class="attention-outer-div">
        <div class="attention-inner-div">
            <img src="Images/big_logo.png" class="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="attention-inner-div1">
                <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Contact Us &emsp;+2000 890 560
            </div>
            <div class="attention-inner-div2">
                <i class="fa fa-behance atten-icon-style" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p atten-icon-style" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter atten-icon-style" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook atten-icon-style" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The fiddle isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by removing the `display:block;` from the media queries.

So you're updated media queries will be :

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px){
.head-outer-div, 
.attention-outer-div{ width:100%;}

.head-inner-div, 
.head-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div, 
.attention-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div2
{display:block; width:100%; float:none; text-align:center;}
.search-div{width:100%;}
.head-inner-div1{margin-bottom:10px;}


   }
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
.head-outer-div, 
.attention-outer-div{ width:100%;}

.head-inner-div, 
.head-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div, 
.attention-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div2
{ width:100%; float:none; text-align:center;}
.search-div{width:100%;}
.head-inner-div1{margin-bottom:10px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
.head-outer-div, 
.attention-outer-div{ width:100%;}

.head-inner-div, 
.head-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div, 
.attention-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div2
{ width:100%; float:none; text-align:center;}
.search-div{width:100%;}
.head-inner-div1{margin-bottom:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
.head-outer-div, 
.attention-outer-div{ width:100%;}

.head-inner-div, 
.head-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div, 
.attention-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div2
{ width:100%; float:none; text-align:center;}
.search-div{width:100%;}
.head-inner-div1{margin-bottom:10px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 320px){
.head-outer-div{ width:320px;}
.head-outer-div, 
.attention-outer-div
{ width:100%; overflow:auto;}

.head-inner-div, 
.head-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div, 
.attention-inner-div1, 
.attention-inner-div2
{ width:100%; float:none; text-align:center;}
.search-div{width:100%;}
.head-inner-div1{margin-bottom:10px;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @David if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the coloring of the element `.attention`.

```
.attention{
    background-color: #8D2228;
}
```

If you require it to only change once you get to a certain point, you can do this instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1999px){
    .attention{
        background-color: #8D2228;
    }
}
```